# Generating IntegralTable via Subprogram/Module in EES

Tags: integral

I am developing a model that involves application of the thermodynamic balance equations (mass, energy and equation of state) to multiple control volumes.  Currently I repeat the system of DAE's as many times as there are control volumes, which is not very efficient. I tried declaring the equations in a SUBPROGRAM or MODULE and making calls to it when I need to.  The following code is a very simple example, aiming to demonstrate the problem:

```js
Module XY(x_0,x)
 dxdt = 1
 x = x_0 + integral(dxdt, t, 0, 5) 
End

$integraltable t: 0.01  x 
w0 = 1
y0 = 2
Call XY(w0,w)
Call XY(y0,y)
```

The code runs OK in EES but results are returned only at the end of integration without the integral table generated.  Any thoughts on how this could be solved?  Thank you!